# Obj-C Inheriting from SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a class defined as

```
@interface Board : SKSpriteNode
+ (Board *) initWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen;
@end

@implementation Board
+ (Board *) initWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen
{
  Board *board = (Board *) [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"turn4_board"];
  return (Board *)board;
}
@end
```

There are other methods/properties but this is the relevant portion. My problem is that after initializing board (via the `SKSpriteNode` call), the variable is of type `SKSpriteNode`. I can't make it of type "Board", thus later run-time calls to an instance of "Board" cause a crash saying that my method doesn't exist in the class `SKSpriteNode`.  I am apparently making a rookie mistake, but I'm starting to go bald over this one.  Please provide the requisite smack upside my head, and then please follow up with a helpful fix/suggestion. Thanks!

I should, perhaps, mention that I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 developing for iOS 7 under MacOS 10.9.4.

Comment: Doh.  I knew it was something basic.  Changing SKSpriteNode to Board worked fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Because you created a `SKSpriteNode` not `Board`. Cast fool the compiler but it won't make it working.

```
@interface Board : SKSpriteNode
+ (instancetype) boardWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen;
@end

@implementation Board
+ (instancetype) boardWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen
{
  return [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"turn4_board"];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a proper init method and conventionally a convenience constructor will start with `boardWith...`:

```
@interface Board : SKSpriteNode
+ (Board *)boardWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen;
- (instancetype)initWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen;
@end

@implementation Board
+ (Board *)boardWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen
{
    return [[Board alloc] initWithScreenSize:screen];
}

- (instancetype)initWithScreenSize:(CGRect)screen
{
    self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"turn4_board"];
    if (self) {
        // Additional init
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```